# Add extra stuff if a custom environment spills to the next page

Tags: environments, page-breaking

All my search attempts just return results for how to force or prevent page breaks. My goal (at this point) *isn't* to control where the page-breaks are, but to react to them. I just want to add some extra markup each time my environment happens to naturally spill across another page break.

### M(n)WE:

I'd like to write something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{Foo}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{Foo}
Hello
\newpage  % Force a new page, in real use, "hello world" would be long enough to spill.
World
\end{Foo}
\end{document}
```

But have the rendered result look as if it was this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{Foo}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{Foo}
Hello

% This gets added wherever needed such that it's the last thing on the page.
\vspace*{\fill}
Continued on the next page.  
\newpage
Continued from the last page.\medskip

World
\end{Foo}
\end{document}
```

The details of the second version are not the point so please don't read much into them. They just sketch how the page should look.

---

I've considered having the environment muck with headers and footers and then resetting them at the end, but that seems to be the kind of hack that is likely to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: BTW: I am aware that things could get funky if the added content then wants to force a line that used to fit off to the next page. More or less anything sane around that is acceptable, it doesn't need to be perfect.

Comment: you really need to say if the text needs to be in he page head/foot which is supported by tex or in the page body (not really supported but you can do some things in some cases) page breaking is asynchronous with the macro expansion and ypesetting so you can not simply execute a macro at the point of a page break, any macros that you insert normally are executed long before any page breaking is decided.

Comment: ... consider a long paragraph spanning pages, all macros with the paragraph are expanded and all text set to font characeters before line breaking happens, then the long line is broken into lines hn the list of lines is broken into pages, so you can not at that point insert text and re-set the paragraph at athe page break.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The extra text needs to be at the bottom of each page if and only if the environment overflows off the bottom of it and at the top of each page if and only if it flows onto it. Exactly where is not of much importance as long as it doesn't do something like make page numbers disappear. (I.e. added to header/footers is okay, *replacing* them is likely not.)

Comment: What I'd like to be told is that there is some sort of hook that I can tap into that defines what "breaking into another pages" amounts to. With that, while the lines from a specific paragraph (or group of them) is being assigned to pages my hook would get called when whatever it is decides a new page is needed, then once the special stuff is done, it reverts to whatever was going on before.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it possible to piggy-back on the longtable environment by adding another environment inside and making use of `\endfoot` / `\endhead` as, for example, in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614928/how-can-i-remove-the-last-continued-from-previous-page-from-my-longtable)?